# Faster render with Workbench?

Tags: animation, workbench-render-engine

What are the tips and tricks for making workbench render faster?
Since I am using workbench for debugging purposes, I don't care much about the quality of the render as long as it gives me a rough idea what the scene looks like.

For an 1080p animation with just a couple of basic objects, it renders at 6 fps on my i5-9600K CPU. I know I can do better since blender's preview runs at 30fps without any issues.

Comment: It renders at 6 fps? Quite quick I'd say... I usually never have any render taking below one second, so rendering 6 frames in one second is fast. And the 30 fps playback in the preview doesn't say anything about rendering performance - because it's just a preview that doesn't create a movie or image sequence.

Answer (score 1):

What a render does and the preview doesn't is save the results to disk. This is possibly the bottleneck here.

It depends a bit on what file format you use and what type your hard drive is. My guess would be that writing uncompressed BMPs onto an SSD might be fastest.

If you are not interested in the actual result images and are running Linux, you could try to put dev/null as your output path...